# find the limit of a function with 0 in the divisor

Tags: calculus, limits

Given the expression below I need to find the limit for $x \to 1$:
$$
\lim_{x \to 1}\frac{\frac{1 + \frac{4}{x}}{1+x} -2.5}{1+x-\frac{2}{x}} \div \frac{x^2+x^3+4}{13x + (x-1)^5}
$$
If we start substituting $x$'s for $1$'s we get $0$ in the divisor which means we can't really do that. I suppose the expression can somehow be transformed and/or simplified such that the divisor will not equal $0$ but I don't see how. I tried proceeding with the expression as it is and eventually received $0$ in the multiple ($\frac{1 + \frac{4}{1}}{1+1} -2.5 = 0$). Wolfram Alpha says the limit is $\approx -2.35$ (after my rounding).

Comment: what is " $:$ " in between the expression?

Comment: I meant division sign. Edited the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some simplification,$$\lim_{x \to 1}\frac{\frac{1 + \frac{4}{x}}{1+x} -2.5}{1+x-\frac{2}{x}} \div \frac{x^2+x^3+4}{13x + (x-1)^5}=
\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{(1+\frac{4}{x}-2.5(1+x))}{(1+x+\frac{2}{x})}\cdot \frac{(13x+(x-1)^5)}{(1+x)(x^2+x^3+4)}$$

Notice  $\lim_{x\to 1} \frac{(13x+(x-1)^5)}{(1+x)(x^2+x^3+4)}=13/12$, we evalute $\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{(1+\frac{4}{x}-2.5(1+x))}{(1+x+\frac{2}{x})}$, we have

$$\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{(1+\frac{4}{x}-2.5(1+x))}{(1+x+\frac{2}{x})}=\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{-2.5x^2-1.5x+4}{x^2+x-2}$$
Observe that the numerator and denominator go to $0$ as $x$ goes to $1$. So we can use L'hopital rule, and we get $$\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{-2.5x^2-1.5x+4}{x^2+x-2}=\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{-5x-1.5}{2x+1}=-13/6$$

So your limit is $-13/6\cdot13/12=-169/72\approx-2.35$

Answer (score 1):

Without l'Hospital:

Simplify things (until some factor(s) $\;x-1\;$ disappear, if possible), and remember that $\;\cfrac ab\div\cfrac cd=\cfrac ab\cdot\cfrac dc\;$:

$$\frac{\frac{1+\frac4x}{1+x}-\frac52}{1+x-\frac2x}\div\frac{x^3+x^2+4}{13x+(x-1)^5}\stackrel{\text{mult. left factor by}\;\frac xx=1}=\frac{\frac{x+4}{1+x}-\frac{5x}2}{x^2+x-2}\cdot\frac{13x+(x-1)^5}{x^3+x^2+4}=$$

$$=\frac{2x+8-5x-5x^2}{2(x+1)(x+2)(x-1)}\cdot\frac{13x+(x-1)^5}{(x+2)(x^2-x+2)}=$$

$$=-\frac{\overbrace{5x^2+3x-8}^{=(5x+8)(x-1)}}{2(x+1)(x+2)(x-1)}\cdot\frac{13x+(x-1)^5}{(x+2)(x^2-x+2)}=$$

$$-\frac{5x+8}{2(x+1)(x+2)}\cdot\frac{13x+(x-1)^5}{(x+2)(x^2-x+2)}\color{red}{\xrightarrow[x\to1]{}-\frac{13}{12}\cdot\frac{13}{3\cdot2}=-\frac{169}{72}}$$